# Spring security success handler ignores always use false

Tags: url, filter, spring-security

I am using a filter in Spring Security configuration, so I can have more parameters from the login page besides username and password. This is the filter for authentication:

```
public SimpleAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        
        SimpleAuthenticationFilter filter = new SimpleAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(failureHandler());       
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler());
        return filter;
    }
```

And this is the success handler. I thought this would work exactly as it worked .defaultSuccessUrl("/home", false) , but it's not...

```
public SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
    
    SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    successHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/home");
    successHandler.setAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl(false);
    
    return successHandler;
}
```

This is the Security configuration:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(resources).permitAll()                 
                .antMatchers("/somePage").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
            .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")         
            .and()
                .csrf().disable();
        
    }
```

Any ideas of what am I missing? The goal is to skip the default target url.

Thanks a million.

Comment: Please show you security configuration

Comment: Ok, I just edited the post showing the configuration.

Comment: When you use `.defaultSuccessUrl("/home", false)` you are defining a `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` that uses the saved request from the session in order to redirect it. So if you request `/home` and ends up in `/login`, upon login successful you are gonna be redirected to `/home`. In your `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` you should set `alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl` to `true`. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My intention was to access directly to the page of the URL after authentication... as it works `.defaultSuccessUrl("/home", false)`; but Marcus gave me the idea for the solution! All I had to do is change the class of the successHandler this way:

```
public SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        successHandler.setAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl(false);
        successHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/home");
        
        return successHandler;
    }
```

Now it works :). Thank you very much for your help!!